# Angular.js $response async update of $scope variable

Tags: asynchronous, angularjs, response

This is my first attempt at working with Angular.js after using Backbone.js for some projects. I used Yeoman to get the initial angular scaffolding setup as well as to manage various dependencies etc.
The first issue I've run into is with the angular $resource service I setup to hit an external API which returns a simple array of names. In using the Chrome web inspector I see that the data is returned as expected but never renders. I suspect this is due to the call by asynchronous and when the page renders there is no data to show. Shortly after the page renders the data is returned from the API but the page never re-renders again.

The Angular docs state pretty clearly in the tutorial that this should happen automagically via the angular data binding but so far it's never worked for me.
I put the code I'm experimenting with now up in a repo on GitHub at https://github.com/chad-skidmore/angular-test
I've not found any documented issues so far regarding this issue after spending the last couple days hacking around to try and get it to work. If I pass an array to the controller it works fine of course which is one reason I think that there is something hosed in the data binding for async external resource calls.
Any pointers or help would be appreciated.

You can also get to the same code on plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/BAHhsT2l1HKnpjiKLZMK

Thanks,
chad

Comment: Just small hint: you can use Plunker (plnkr.co) to play with AngularJS and put snippets there. It is also great tool to share snippets. Note you can add custom .json files there to emulate backend.

Comment: For those that are inclined to use plnkr rather than pulling from the repo use this: http://plnkr.co/edit/BAHhsT2l1HKnpjiKLZMK

Comment: May be check console/network for some other errors... I've just slighlty modified your source and it works: http://plnkr.co/edit/O7Tud59k80ej5AdMLwGm?p=preview

Comment: API isn't returning JSONP..just JSON so is cross domain security issue

Comment: Thank you charlietfl  I was looking at the client side so much I didn't catch that. Changing the node/express backend to deliver JSONP and adding the callback option in the angular service did the trick.

Comment: Just don't forget to provide and accept the answer if you've found the solution.